# How is user gaining Remote access via SonicWall without VPN

Tags: vpn, firewall, sonicwall

Hello and thanks in advance for your advice.  I recently started supporting a small business and have a problem I can't figure out.  The office has 6 remote employees who access the office network via Global VPN software connecting to a TZ210 SonicWall.  They use company supplied machines to run the VPN software and connect to desktops in the office.  This company runs some data-intensive apps and they don't perform well over the internet so this was the preferred setup and it works very well.

I have found one exception.  He doesn't remote into a machine in the office, he runs the apps from his desktop.  Somehow, this user connects to the network without a VPN connection (and has no VPN account on the firwall) and has been  working for months.  I found out because he was having performance issues and started complaining.  I created a VPN login and installed the software; it connects successfully.  When we try to Remote Desktop to his machine in the office the RD software throws an "Internal Error" while connecting.  However, if I don't enable the VPN, he can connect to his remote desktop.  So, something in the firewall is letting him in but I have no clue where to start looking?

Here are some relevant details:
("computer" refers to his machine outside the network)
 - Computer is running windows 7
 - Computer is not joined to the domain
 - IP and DNS are set to dynamic
 - Firewall is a SonicWall TZ210

Any suggestions where to start looking are appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if there's a NAT rule that allow traffic coming from the Internet to reach the internal system?

Comment: There are many ways this could be done.  There could be a static NAT rule (port forwarding), as @JFL suggests.  He could be using a 3rd party application such a GoToMyPC, or some other remote control application.  I should point out that desktop configuration questions are off-topic for this forum.  Questions about PC configuration can be asked on [sf].

Comment: Ron, I know there is no other Remote software involved and I have used TeamViewer to confirm the steps.  I don't see this as a desktop config issue but truly a firewall issue.  The reason is, his current process violates the companies current policy and I need to plug the "hole" in the firewall.

I am still working on researching the NAT rule.  I only see four on the Sonic Wall that can be edited, and none seem to point to this issue.  I think they are all auto-configured rules....still looking though.

Comment: Ok, I found an Address Object that specifies the IP address of my remote user's ISP.  So now I need to figure out how this address object is used?  Does it sound like I'm headed down the right path?

Comment: You said you have used TeamViewer to confirm the steps, so how does je connect from Computer to his machine in the office? What software (eg. Remote Desktop Connection) and to what IP/name does he connect? Is it the office WAN IP? He is perhaps connection via RDP on a non-standard port (which is why you can't connect when you try to RDP to his machine)? Look at both the inbound NAT rules and the WAN > LAN Firewall rules. Or maybe it's a non-GVC VPN, such as L2TP or SSL-VPN, or a VNC connection. If you can connect to his machine at home: see how he is connecting.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out.  There is a site-to-site connection set up.  Under the VPN Policies, there is one for his IP range.  Am I interpreting that correctly?  I tried to click on "Edit" to get more details but its not grayed out and it doesn't do anything?   same for "Add"....<ugh>  but that's a different problem!

Answer (score 0):

Disable that Site to site connection.  It sounds like that is how he was getting in.